# Is it possible to use custom routes for celery's canvas primitives?

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have distinct Rabbit queues each dedicated to a special kind of order processing:

```py
# tasks.py

@celery.task
def process_order_for_product_x(order_id):
    pass  # elided ...


@celery.task
def process_order_for_product_y(order_id):
    pass  # elided ...


# settings.py

CELERY_QUEUES = {
    "black_hole": {
        "binding_key": "black_hole",
        "queue_arguments": {"x-ha-policy": "all"}
    },
    "product_x": {
        "binding_key": "product_x",
        "queue_arguments": {"x-ha-policy": "all"}
    },
    "product_y": {
        "binding_key": "product_y",
        "queue_arguments": {"x-ha-policy": "all"}
    },
```

We have a policy of enforcing explicit routing by setting `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'black_hole'` and then never consuming from `black_hole`.

Each of these tasks may use celery's canvas primitives, like so:

```py
# tasks.py

@celery.task
def process_order_for_product_x(order_id):
    # These can run in parallel
    stage_1_group = group(do_something.si(order_id),
                          do_something_else.si(order_id))

    # These can run in parallel
    another_group = group(do_something_at_end.si(order_id),
                          do_something_else_at_end.si(order_id))

    # These run in a linear sequence
    process_task = chain(
        stage_1_group,
        do_something_dependent_on_stage_1.si(order_id),
        another_group)

    process_task.apply_async()
```

Supposing I want specific uses of `celery.group`, `celery.chord`, `celery.chord_unlock`, and other canvas tasks to flow through the queue for its corresponding product, rather than getting trapped in a `black_hole`, is there a way to invoke each particular canvas task with either a custom task name or custom routing_key?

For reasons I won't go into I would prefer to not send all `celery.*` tasks to a catch-all `celery_canvas` queue, which is what I am doing in the meantime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method allows you to route Celery canvas tasks to the queue of a callback task.

It is possible to specify a custom class-based task router for Celery as described [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#routers).

Let's focus on the `celery.chord_unlock` task. Its signature is defined [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/app/builtins.py).

```
def unlock_chord(self, group_id, callback, ...):
```

The second positional argument is the signature of the chord callback task.

Task signatures in Celery are basically dicts, so that gives us an opportunity to access task options, including the task queue name.

Here is an example:

```
class CeleryRouter(object):
    def route_for_task(self, task, args=None, kwargs=None):
        if task == 'celery.chord_unlock':
            callback_signature = args[1]
            options = callback_signature.get('options')
            if options:
                queue = options.get('queue')
                if queue:
                    return {'queue': queue}
```

Add it to the Celery config:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = (CeleryRouter(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Celery in my project. For some scenarios I need task to chain though different queues:

```py
chain(get_staff.s(url), save_staff.s(dt, partner_id, url))()
```

Those two functions declared like so:

```py
@task(queue='celery_gevent')
def get_staff(source_url):

@task # send to default queue
def save_staff(suggests, dt, partner, url):
```

btw, **celery_gevent** is handled by worker with **gevent** pool to make http requests.

This example, how you can specify queue *implicitly*. Also you can *explicitly* put task in a different queue by specifying additional params, like so:

```
In [1]: add.apply_async([4,5])
Out[1]: <AsyncResult: bda3dedd-c2c4-44db-be8e-6a97e718f8b0>

$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Listing queues ...
celery  1
...done.

In [2]: add.apply_async([4,5], queue='your_product')
Out[2]: <AsyncResult: 934f6161-298b-468b-9716-3da6fae58fa5>

$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
Listing queues ...
celery  1
your_product    1
...done.
```

You can run whole canvas in custom queue:

```py
process_task.apply_async(queue='your_queue')
```

Try to specify queue_name inside `@task` decorator. This should help.

Links:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/task.html#Task.apply_async